# What are the differences between "Raum" and "Zimmer"?

Tags: meaning

Can I use both words as **"room"**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can use both:

**Raum** = Room

**Weltraum** = Space

**Zimmer** = A room in a house. Particularly a home.

**Raum** = A room in a house or a conference room. A room in any building

**Zimmer** is more private than room. (In Hotels you refer to the rooms you can book as Zimmer. - These Zimmer come with locks and keys so you can have some privacy.)

You would not call a conference room a **Zimmer**.

But then again it depends on where in Germany you are from.

You could also use the word **Stube** for Room. Maybe less so for Zimmer.

Stube is what the sleeping rooms in the Kaserne of the German army are called. They are certainly less private and have multiple occupants.

**Stube**/**Wohnzimmer** is also the "Entertainment" and socializing room. So by definition it is **less** **private** and **more** **open**. Wenn referring to "**Gute** **Stube**" it refers to a room that is "**better**" than the other rooms.

I don't know since **Stube** is not a word I use much. I would use it mostly for the living room. And even then I don't say Stube. I say **Wohnzimmer.**

Comment: It's Wohnzimmer and Weltraum. Why the hyphen?

Comment: Your room at the Bundeswehr barracks is always called Stube.

Comment: Hotel rooms are also always called Zimmer, never Raum.

Comment: Generally I'd say a Raum is larger than a Zimmer.

Comment: @Emanuel: Weil er dachte, die Leser seien zu doof die Wortbestandteile "Raum" und "Zimmer" kleingeschrieben und ohne Bindestrich zu entdecken. :)

Comment: @Robert: Im Osten wurde generell von einer "2-Raumwohnung" in Anzeigen gesprochen, wo im Westen "2 Zimmerwohnung" stand. Mit der Zimmergröße hat das nichts zu tun. Großbürgerliche Raucherzimmer sind sicher auch größer als Abstellräume im sozialen Wohnungsbau.

Comment: @user unknown Guter "Ost/West"-Einwand. Weil es aber immer weniger großbürgerliche Raucherzimmer gibt, bleibe ich bei meiner Generalisierung, dass Räume größer als Zimmer sind --- Ausnahmen bestätigen die Regel.

Comment: @Robert A "Zimmer" is always a "Raum"; thus a "Raum" cannot be larger than a "Zimmer".

Comment: This answer missed an important meaning for "Raum" - its just a 3D space, as in "Federn sind sehr leicht, sie nehmen viel Raum ein". It also gives imprecise and misleading meanings for Stube and Zimmer.

Answer (score 8):

Zimmer and Raum both refer to "room" (in a building) in somewhat different contexts.

Zimmer refers to a "private" room. For a "public" room such as a conference room or a party room, use Raum.

Raum has the additional meaning of "room" in the sense of "space," and even regarding time periods.

Comment: Im Osten wurde generell von einer "2-Raumwohnung" in Anzeigen gesprochen, wo im Westen "2 Zimmerwohnung" stand. Mit der Privatheit hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: @userunknown: Der Begriff "Raum" funktioniert definitiv auch für private Räume. Aber hast Du ein Beispiel für die Verwendung von "Zimmer" für einen öffentlichen Raum?

Comment: Raum kann auch zeitlich sein: Zeitraum

Comment: @RomanReiner: You reminded me of something I had forgotten. So I added it to the answer.

Comment: @celtschk: Konferrenzzimmer.

Answer (score 6):

Der *Raum* ist ein allgemeinerer Begriff. Es ist–physikalisch ausgedrückt–ein [sich in drei Dimensionen erstreckende geometrische Größe](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Raum). Der Begriff *Raum* kann einen Bereich bezeichnen, der als Nutzfläche genutzt wird oder zum Aufenthalt zur Verfügung steht. Letzteres(also Aufenthalt) wird gängigerweise als *Zimmer* bezeichnet. *Zimmer* ist somit ein Unterbegriff von *Raum*.

Ein *Zimmer* ist ein Raum innerhalb einer Wohnung oder Hauses. Auch Hotels und Jugendherbergen haben *Zimmer*. *Zimmer* befinden sich also nur dort, wo Menschen 'wohnen'. In anderen Gebäuden (z.b. Bürogebäuden) findet man nur *Räume*. Zimmer sind also "häusliche" Räume oder–wie eingangs schon erwähnt–schlicht ein Raum, der dem "Aufenthalt" dient.

Beispielsweise ist eine Küche strikt gesehen kein Zimmer, nur ein Raum. Häufig befindet sich die Küchenzeile aber im selben Raum wie die Wohnzimmergarnitur. Es ist dann natürlich schwierig dies klar abzugrenzen.

Comment: Bin fast 100% einig mit dir, gäbe es nicht ein paar Ausnahmen, die ein *Zimmer*  bezeichnen, in dem keiner "wohnt" - *Krankenzimmer* (ok, da wohnt jemand zumindestens vorübergehend drin), "Arztzimmer" oder "Schreibzimmer" (schon wieder Kaserne) oder gar "Bernsteinzimmer" - da wohnt auch keiner drin. (vom "Frauenzimmer" nicht zu reden ;)

Comment: In Ostberlin sagt man man Zweiraumwohnung.

Comment: @tofro Du hättest gar nicht so weit ausholen müssen. Das Badezimmer hätte auch schon gereicht. Da 'wohnt' man schließlich auch nicht. Es gibt mit Sicherheit Ausnahmen, aber die bestätigen bekanntlich nur die Regel. :)

Comment: @userunknown Das ist aber was anderes als eine Zweizimmerwohnung

Comment: @tofro Inwiefern?

Comment: @userunknown eine Zweiraumwohnung ist per Definition eine Wohnung mit zwei Räumen, z.B. Küche und ein Zimmer. Eine Küche und ein Zimmer ist aber eine *Einzimmerwohnung*.

Comment: Und wer hat das definiert? Du soeben? Du bist aber keine autoritative Quelle und Deine Behauptung ist schlicht falsch, siehe  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweiraumwohnung und https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zweiraumwohnung .

Comment: Personalausweise gibt's in Zimmer A13. Da wohnt dann aber auch keiner.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the points have been covered in the previous replies. Just want to add the below conjugations :

Der Raum = space (There's space in the car)

Der Raum = room (A conference/discussion room maybe)

Das Zimmer = room (A room in a house)

Comment: You may want to add a bit more details why you believe your answer is better than the existing answers, or which specific point is added.

Comment: Oder auch Konferenzzimmer. Schlafraum und Vorraum sind üblicherweise auch in Häusern.