# Bedeutung von "Zweizimmerwohnung" vs. "Zweiraumwohnung"

Tags: difference, regional

Inspiriert von [What are the differences between "Raum" and "Zimmer"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/14930/what-are-the-differences-between-raum-and-zimmer?rq=1) wollte ich eine mich schon länger beschäftigende Frage klären. Leider habe ich dazu nur [einen Beitrag im Juraforum](http://www.juraforum.de/forum/t/definition-2-zimmer-wohnung-wohnkueche.315150/) gefunden, der die Frage aber nicht klärt. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweiraumwohnung) hat eine vielversprechende Begriffsklärung, die eine Antwort auf meine Frage andeutet, der Link läuft allerdings ins Leere.

In den östlichen Bundesländern werden Wohnungen m. W. als *Einraumwohnung*, *Zweiraumwohnung* etc. bezeichnet, wohingegen im Westen *Einzimmerwohnung*, *Zweizimmerwohnung* etc. gängig ist.

Meinem Verständnis nach wird ein Raum nur dann als *Zimmer* bezeichnet, wenn er dem längeren Aufenthalt von Personen dient (Wohnzimmer, Schlafzimmer, Kinderzimmer, Arbeitszimmer), während andere Räume anders heißen: Küche, Flur, Abstellkammer. Dementsprechend werden sie bei der Wohnungsbezeichnung auch nicht mitgezählt. Eine Zweizimmerwohnung kann also im Extremfall (wenn auch unwahrscheinlich) durchaus aus sieben Räumen bestehen: Wohnzimmer, Schlafzimmer, Küche, Bad, Gäste-WC, Flur, Abstellkammer.

Würde man so eine Wohnung jetzt als *Zweiraumwohnung* bezeichnen, weil auch in diesem Fall nur die *Zimmer* gezählt werden, oder würde man tatsächlich von einer *Siebenraumwohnung* sprechen, oder aus irgendwelchen Gründen von etwas dazwischen?

Comment: Das Bade-*Zimmer* dient »dem längeren Aufenthalt von Personen«?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich stimme zu, dass Zweiraumwohnung einfach das in Ostdeutschland gebräuchliche Wort für die im Westen verwendete Zweizimmerwohnung ist.

Allerdings suggeriert "Raum" meiner Ansicht nach auch eine gewisse Größe. Ich denke dabei an Maklersprache:

> Und das hier ist der Wohnraum!

… sagt der Makler und schwenkt dabei großzügig seinen ausgestreckten Arm von links nach rechts. Mit "Wohnzimmer" ist das nicht so eindrucksvoll.

Weder bei Zweiraum- noch bei Zweizimmerwohnung werden die Räume/Zimmer der -- ich nenn's mal -- Infrastruktur (Küche, Bad, Flur) mitgezählt. Soviel ich weiss, wird in USA und UK gerne nur die Anzahl der Schlafzimmer (bedrooms) angegeben. Offenbar geht man dort davon aus, dass ein Wohnzimmer (living room, reception room) *immer* vorhanden ist.

Answer (score 1):

Ich versuch's mal mit logischem Ausschluß:

Eine Wohnung, die aus nur zwei (Neben-)Räumen in der engsten Begriffsdefinition gegen "Zimmer" (z.B. "Bad" und "Küche") bestehen würde, wäre keine Wohnung, weil man ja nicht drin wohnen kann. Meiner Ansicht nach kann "Zweiraumwohnung" als ex-DDR-Begriff also nur exakt dasselbe bedeuten wie "Zweizimmerwohnung" im Westen.

Wäre das nicht so, dann wäre eine westdeutsch bezeichnete "2 Zimmer, Küche, Bad"-Wohnung ja eine "Vierraumwohnung".

Comment: In Ostberlin habe ich auch schon eine 2-Zimmer-Küche-Flur-Wohnung bewohnt. Klo gab's im Treppenhaus und eine Badeanstalt eine Straße weiter.

Comment: Mir hat man in Bayern (»auf dem Land«) eine billige Zweizimmer-Küche-Flur-Wohnung mit Klo im Treppenhaus (wo/ob Bad weiß ich nicht mehr) angeboten, das gibts also nicht nur dort ;).